# Making a 'contains' type GET query over a REST API, with Services?

Tags: 8, services

I've installed Services (and Services Views) so I can expose my drupal site as a RESTful API.

All my filters are working, but not the one that queries a taxonomy term array.

Here is an example JSO:

```
{
    name: "AngularJS",
    quad: "Solution Technology",
    desc: "AngularJS is an open-source web application framework, maintained by Google and community, that assists with creating single-page applications, one-page web applications that only require HTML, CSS, and JavaScript on the client side. Its goal is to augment web applications with model?view?controller (MVC) capability, in an effort to make both development and testing easier. (Source Wikipedia)",
    tid: "123",
    group: [
        "Web Application Framework",
        "User Interface"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to query this with the string `localhost/drupal/rest/technologies.json?group=Web%20Application%20Framework`. Is this the right syntax?

Here are my settings:

[image: First Settings page]
[image: Second Settings page]